# Rails 3 - validation rules with regex

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, model

With this rule

```
validates_format_of :numbers, :with => /^[0-9]{15}$/, :message => "error message"
```

will be the item `:numbers` valid only with the regex above. But is possible to set, that the item `:numbers` could be send as an empty or like a 15 digits? I can't find the right combination of validation rules.

Answer (score 2):

Just add the allow_blank option like:

```
validates_format_of :numbers, :with => /^[0-9]{15}$/, :allow_blank => true
```

See [docs](http://ar.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods.html#M000087) for further information.